# localhost problem internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-6, xampp

I have installed xampp 1.7.3. After starting apache and mysql service when I write http://localhost/ in the internet explorer address bar it shows 'The page cannot be displayed'. But for Firefox it creates no problem and shows Xampp index.php page.

Now how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you've flushed you cache - 
Also try the ip address `127.0.0.1`

Sounds daft but ensure IE6 can actually see the web, as it may be a case of changing your connection settings -

I remember correctly you had the ability to edit the localhost connections in the setting - Unfortuntely I havent used a real IE for a while so I'm not sure. I believe there is a check box in the settings "bypass for local connections" for your proxy or settings.

Also ensure you have "auto detect" for your connection settings.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is an option for bypassing local connection.

Comment: Hey - there you are. No problems dude.